# Wifi not works, is switched off?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I'm trying, for 6 months, to resume my old netbook, a Packarbell Dot s2 (i686). I'm trying to install on that Ubuntu, and there is no problem but no wifi is found. In the pc there is this chip:
[image: Wifi Chip]
but I don't find any driver to work with it or, I don't know if it is possible, it can be switched off. I remember that, when on this netbook there was windows, with keyboard combination Fn+F2 I could turn it off/on, and now no wifi led is on. There is some thing that I can do with ubuntu to understand if is recognise and switch it on?

Answer (score 0):

The "atk5k" driver should work with that card, but it can get crafty.

The card is quite old, so all I could find are docs for ubuntu 9.10, still it is worth a try:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Atheros

Comment: The wifi on that card is actually an AR9285 which is supported by ath9k.  Another card is marked AR5B195 and it uses the same wifi along with the AR3012 bluetooth